# How to create a disabled textbox in MVC razor view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I want to create text area which will be disabled or invisible at starting.
There's a dropdown list, on selection of last option i.e other, it should enable or make the text area visible and take the value and pass to controller on submission.

Comment: `new { disabled = "true"}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
@Html.TextArea("Name", null, new { disabled="disabled" })
```

For You:

```
<div> 
        @Html.TextArea("Name", null, new { disabled="true" })
        @Html.DropDownList("switch", new List<SelectListItem>() { 
    new SelectListItem(){Text="Enable", Value="Enable"},
    new SelectListItem(){Text="Disable", Value="Disable", Selected=true},
   })
    </div>

    <script>

 $(function ($) {

        var dropDown = $("#switch");
        var txtName = $("#Name");

        dropDown.change(function () {
            if (dropDown.val() === "Disable")
            {
                txtName.attr("disabled", true);
            }
            else {
                txtName.removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        })


    })(jQuery)



    </script>
```

Comment: I want to create text area which will be disabled or invisible at starting. There's a dropdown list, on selection of last option i.e other, it should enable or make the text area visible and take the value and pass to controller on submission.  I think will have to use  a jquery for making it enable on selection of dropdown list option with text="Other".  Can you help me with this?

Comment: did you add jquery???Add this into <head> tag
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`.In my project it works

Comment: Ya,I forgot to add jquery.. Now its working.. Thankx :-)

Comment: Can I hide the textbox for all other selection other than the last option?

Comment: you can add many items with value and in jquery choose by their's value what they must to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should hide the text area, not only disable it. What you can do is add the html :

```
@Html.TextArea("Text", null, new { @class="hiddenOptionArea", disabled="disabled" })
```

and apply the class:

```
hiddenOptionArea {
    display:none
}
```

Also you better use @Html.EditorFor and make yourself a template for your model, so that you can reuse your html wherever you need it - you can find the link here: http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/

Comment: I want to create text area which will be disabled or invisible at starting. There's a dropdown list, on selection of last option i.e other, it should enable or make the text area visible and take the value and pass to controller on submission.  I think will have to use  a jquery for making it enable on selection of dropdown list option with text="Other".  Can you help me with this?

Comment: please provide us some code so i can help you with your problem. what is your html ? Do you need to use this more than once ? The implementation depends on what do you want to achieve with this ;]

Comment: I have a dropdown list where there's some option,if the option user wants is not present in the drop down selection I want to enable his textbox so that the user can enter his selection.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this for creating disabled textArea

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.property, new { id = "txtId", disabled = "disabled" })
```